# Bigquery - calculate user active sessions from access history

Tags: google-bigquery

I am new to BQ, and not sure how much it will cost by doing this query.

I have a table that records access time of all users, like the following:

```
user_id     access_time
-------------------------------------
user_a      2015-06-15 14:12:12
user_b      2015-06-15 14:12:12
user_a      2015-06-15 14:12:13
user_a      2015-06-15 14:12:19
user_a      2015-06-15 14:12:28
user_a      2015-06-15 19:32:15
user_a      2015-06-15 19:32:19
```

I want to generate an active session table to represent all the activity window of users. Each session contains duration and start time.

Session will expire if the next access is not within 10 seconds.

The example of the session table would be:

```
session_id    user_id    session_start_time    duration
------------------------------------------------------------
1             user_a     2015-06-15 14:12:12   16
2             user_b     2015-06-15 14:12:12   0
3             user_a     2015-06-15 19:32:15   4
```

It seems that BQ does not support customised function, how can I achieve this by one single query?

Thanks in advance!

---

UPDATE:

Fixed the example.

Answer (score 4):

To illustrate the approach using data from your example, here is how the query would which shows new sessions with start times look like:

```
select user, ts start_time from (
select user, ifnull(seconds - prev_seconds > 10, true) new_session from (
select user, ts, seconds, lag(seconds, 1) over(partition by user order by seconds) prev_seconds from
(select user, ts, integer(ts/1000000) seconds from
(select 'user_a' user,  timestamp('2015-06-15 14:12:12') ts),
(select 'user_b' user,  timestamp('2015-06-15 14:12:12') ts),
(select 'user_a' user,  timestamp('2015-06-15 14:12:13') ts),
(select 'user_a' user,  timestamp('2015-06-15 14:12:19') ts),
(select 'user_a' user,  timestamp('2015-06-15 14:12:28') ts),
(select 'user_a' user,  timestamp('2015-06-15 19:32:15') ts),
(select 'user_a' user,  timestamp('2015-06-15 19:32:19') ts))))
where new_session
```

To also get durations of the session, instead of doing self join, we can run another window function. Basically first we find beginning and end of sessions, and then compute difference between them:

```
select user, ts, if(next_is_last, next_seconds - seconds, 0) duration
from (
select 
  user, new_session, last_session, ts, seconds,
  lead(seconds, 1) over(partition by user order by seconds) next_seconds,
  lead(last_session, 1) over(partition by user order by seconds) next_is_last
from (
select 
  user,
  ts,
  ifnull(seconds - prev_seconds > 10, true) new_session,
  ifnull(next_seconds - seconds > 10, true) last_session
from (
select 
  user, 
  ts, 
  seconds, 
  lag(seconds, 1) over(partition by user order by seconds) prev_seconds,
  lead(seconds, 1) over(partition by user order by seconds) next_seconds 
from
(select user, ts, integer(ts/1000000) seconds from
(select 'user_a' user,  timestamp('2015-06-15 14:12:12') ts),
(select 'user_b' user,  timestamp('2015-06-15 14:12:12') ts),
(select 'user_a' user,  timestamp('2015-06-15 14:12:13') ts),
(select 'user_a' user,  timestamp('2015-06-15 14:12:19') ts),
(select 'user_a' user,  timestamp('2015-06-15 14:12:28') ts),
(select 'user_a' user,  timestamp('2015-06-15 19:32:15') ts),
(select 'user_a' user,  timestamp('2015-06-15 19:32:19') ts))))
where new_session or last_session)
where new_session
```

This results in:

```
Row user    ts                       duration    
1   user_a  2015-06-15 14:12:12 UTC  16  
2   user_a  2015-06-15 19:32:15 UTC  4   
3   user_b  2015-06-15 14:12:12 UTC  0
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Maybe I described my question not clear. Instead of counting every interval of access as a session, I want to concat all the continuous intervals into one session if they are not broken by a timeout interval. That's why `user_a` in my example only has two sessions. The first 3 intervals are joint into one session which last for 16 seconds.

Comment: If you run the query above - you will get exactly the result you described - user_a will have two sessions.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I only executed the subquery of the top query. You are right, There are two sessions for user_a. But I really need the durations. I managed to generate every interval of access and whether they are the beginning of the session, but I don't know how sum the duration up of each session.Any idea?

Comment: OK, I extended the query to show how to compute duration as well.

Answer (score 2):

Without access to the dataset itself it would be a bit hard for me to answer, but here's the logical flow I would implement:

1. For each event, use the LEAD() function to find the next access time; calculate the difference, and run an if statement on the result to flag the record as "new session" 1/0. Take only the new sessions. This will give you a sub-table of all the session start periods
2. Follow the exact same steps, with the exception of flagging new sessions, to get the duration of each access
3. Join the two sub-tables on something like:

   on a.user_id = b.user_id and b.access_time >= a.session_start_time and b.access_time < next_session_time
4. Then just sum for each user and session

Might not be the most efficient approach (save partial results to a temp table to avoid running over all the data twice), but it should work

Answer (score 0):

Ok, enlightened by [Mosha's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30872694/1105455), I tried out this solution.
The key points are:

1. use window function to folder the table.
2. rule out the intervals between start and end of the session.
3. use window function again to calculate the duration.

Here is the script:

```
select user, 
  case
    when not new_session and end_of_session then seconds - start_time
    when end_of_session  and end_of_session then 0
  end as duration,
  case 
    when not new_session and end_of_session then start_time
    when new_session and end_of_session then seconds
  end as session_start,
  seconds as session_end from
(select *, lag(seconds, 1) over (partition by user order by seconds, prev_seconds) as start_time from
(select user, seconds , new_session, ifnull(end_session_temp, true) end_of_session, prev_seconds from
(select user, seconds , new_session, prev_seconds, lead(new_session, 1) over (partition by user order by seconds, prev_seconds) as end_session_temp from
(select user, seconds, new_session, prev_seconds from 
(select user, seconds, prev_seconds, ifnull(seconds - prev_seconds > 10, true) new_session from 
(select user, ts, seconds, lag(seconds, 1) over(partition by user order by seconds) as prev_seconds from
(select user, ts, integer(ts/1000000) seconds from
(select 'user_a' user,  timestamp('2015-06-15 14:12:12') ts),
(select 'user_b' user,  timestamp('2015-06-15 14:12:12') ts),
(select 'user_a' user,  timestamp('2015-06-15 14:12:13') ts),
(select 'user_a' user,  timestamp('2015-06-15 14:12:19') ts),
(select 'user_a' user,  timestamp('2015-06-15 14:12:28') ts),
(select 'user_a' user,  timestamp('2015-06-15 19:32:15') ts),
(select 'user_a' user,  timestamp('2015-06-15 19:32:19') ts))))))
where (new_session or end_session_temp  is null or end_session_temp)))
where not (new_session and not end_of_session)
```

The output is:

```
Row         user        duration    session_start   session_end  
1           user_b      0           1434377532      1434377532   
2           user_a      16          1434377532      1434377548   
3           user_a      4           1434396735      1434396739
```